# Add password to Django Group model

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

Is it possible to password protect groups so that a user can only join a group if the user has a password for that group?

I know it's possible to add fields to the Group model with

`Group.add_to_class('password', CharField(max_length=180, null=True, blank=True))`

But how can I implement this in a secure way? I want the password to be properly hashed and stored. In essence, how can I add the `User` password field to `Group` as well?

EDIT:

The docstring for the `Group` class in the source.

> Groups are a generic way of categorizing users to apply permissions,
>   or some other label, to those users. A user can belong to any number
>   of groups.
>
> Beyond permissions, groups are a convenient way to categorize users to
>   apply some label, or extended functionality, to them.

All I'm using a group for here is a label, and I want to password protect that label for when users try to join.

Comment: That's not what Django groups are for. Users don't put themselves into a group, an admin does. Are you sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What is the reason you want this feature for?

Comment: Rather than create my own model to group users together, I thought I could take advantage of Django's built in  `Group` model, which is providing everything I need save for a way to password protect the group.

Comment: In essence, you want Users to be able to join Groups with a password. Is the password specific to the Group (all users in a Group use the same password) or specific to the User and Group (each User has one password per Group)?

Comment: Specific to the group. All users would access the group using the same password. Passwords need only be distinct for different groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considering your responses in the comments, I believe your best bet will be to subclass `Group` and then implement an authentication procedure within it. Then you can use the functions `make_password`, `check_password`, and `is_password_usable` as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers) to manage the authentication process.